# How to add annotation information in each frame of a stack image?

Tags: dm-script

I know how to add the arrows in a single image displayed front, but now I need to add the arrow annotations on each frame of a image stack to indicate the contrast change position and show them using the GSM "slice player". How to do it?

Comment: I guess that the "GSM 'slice player'" needs the stack image as one piece, does it? Otherwise you could add arrow annotations (`NewArrowAnnotation()`) to the image displays of each image in your stack.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between a 2D image and a 3D stack in DigitalMicrograph. Both are just dimensional data. As such "slices" in a Stack do neither have their individual tags nor annotations - there is just a single imageTagGroup and a single imageDisplays.

So to achieve what you want you need a different approach. You need to *move your annotation whenever the display updates to shows a different slice.*

In order to do this, you need to add a display-listener to your image display and act on the *slice_property_changed* event.

A basic example script for this:

```c
Class CStackAnno
{
    ImageDisplay    disp
    Component       arrow
    Number          ListenerID
        
    // This method is called whenever the imagedisplay fires the slice update event
    void OnSlicePropChanged( object self, Number disp_flags, ImageDisplay disp, Number flags1, Number flags2, object slice_id_beg, object slice_id_end )
    {
        image img := disp.ImageDisplayGetImage()
        if ( 3 != img.ImageGetNumDimensions() ) return
        if ( !arrow.ComponentIsValid() ) return
        
        number sx = img.imageGetDimensionsize(0)
        number sy = img.imageGetDimensionsize(1)
        number sz = img.imageGetDimensionsize(2)
        number start, end
        disp.ImageDisplayGetDisplayedLayers( start, end )
        number kLineEndPoint = 2
        arrow.ComponentSetControlPoint( kLineEndPoint, sx/sz * start, sx/sz * start, 0 )
    }
        
    Object Launch( object self, image Img ) 
    {
        if ( !img.ImageIsValid() ) Throw( "Invalid input image." )
        if ( 3 != img.ImageGetNumDimensions() ) Throw( "This script only supports 3D images." )
        disp = img.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
        
        // Register DisplayListener to catch when it updates
        ListenerID  = disp.ImageDisplayAddEventListener( self, "slice_property_changed:OnSlicePropChanged" )
        
        // Add the annotation
        arrow = NewArrowAnnotation( img.ImageGetDimensionSize(1)/5, img.ImageGetDimensionSize(0)*4/5, 0, 0 )        
        arrow.ComponentSetForegroundColor( 0, 0.5 , 1 )
        arrow.ComponentSetBackgroundColor( 0, 0.8 , 1 )
        arrow.ComponentSetDrawingMode( 1 )
        disp.ComponentAddChildAtEnd( arrow )

        return self
    }
    
}

//Main call
image fImg
GetFrontImage(fImg)
Alloc(CStackAnno).Launch(fImg)
```

Comment: woooo! It seems too cool but I need time to understant it! :) By the way, could I add the arrows or  text annonation on each slice of the stake and export them as colored image seperately using "ImageDisplaySetDisplayedLayers()" as the way you suggested in my another question So I can combine them into a stack again by import series or make a movie with those seperate images.

Comment: @YuanYao Yes, and Yes.